# Inline formset not rendering form field

Tags: python, django, formset, inline-formset

I have models:

```
class MediaInfo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True)
    media_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Media(models.Model):
    media_files = models.ForeignKey(MediaInfo) # I want ManyToManyField but it gives error saying no ForeignKey relation
```

Here I used Inline Formset to select multiple file.

What I wanted was I wanted a browser button on template and when I click that I could select multiple file or images with all those title and description informations.

For this I wrote a view:

```
def MediaAddView(request):
MediaInlineFormset = inlineformset_factory(MediaInfo, Media)
if request.method == "POST":
    formset = MediaInlineFormset(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("someurl")
    else:
        return render_to_response("media_add.html", {"formset":formset,})
else:
    formset = MediaInlineFormset()
    return render_to_response("media_add.html", {"formset":formset,})
```

and my template media_add.html

```
{% block content %}
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
{{form.id}}
<ul>
    <li>{{form.media_file}}</li>
</ul>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>
{% endblock %}
```

When I do this in my template I see nothing just 3 dots of list (li).
Like I said I wanted a browse button and when I click it I wanted to select and upload multiple files.

Whats wrong in here ? Can anyone guide me ?